# Is it possible to access ios photo library with file-system

Tags: ios, nativescript

Is there a way to access the photo-library on ios with the nativescript-filesysten plugin. I can access the knownfolders and even the app folders, but even though i have requested permission for the NSPhotoLibrary I dont find any information for accessing this folder.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way you could use {N} file-system apis to access photo library.

Even if you use photo library apis, you would still get a reference to PHAsset, no direct file access is allowed in there.